# how to read all date from PostgreSQL with array field jpa/hibernate ejb

Tags: arrays, hibernate, jpa, ejb, field

i had problem to read all date from db PostgreSQL and  jpa/hibernate ejb
my table has array field see below :

```
   @Entity
   public class MyTable{
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String[] values;

     @Type(type = "com.usertype.StringArrayUserType")
     public String[] getValues(){
         return values;
     }

     public void setValues(String[] values){
         this.values = values;
     }
   }
```

---

and user type class like this :

```
package com.almasprocess.model.bl.en;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;
public class StringArrayUserType implements UserType {

    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (String[]) this.deepCopy(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == null) {
            return y == null;
        }
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        if(resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null){
            return new Integer[0];
        }

        Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
        String[] javaArray = (String[]) array.getArray();
        return javaArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
        if (value == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
        } else {
            String[] castObject = (String[]) value;
            Array array = connection.createArrayOf("varchar", castObject);
            statement.setArray(index, array);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)       throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String[]> returnedClass() {
        return String[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
    }

}
```

---

and read date like this in ejb class :

```
 public List readMailBank(){
        String query = "select mt from mytable mt";
        TypedQuery<StringArrayUserType> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query , StringArrayUserType.class);
        List<StringArrayUserType> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
```

or like this sample code :

```
 public List readMailBank(){
        Type stringType = (Type) new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver()).custom(StringArrayUserType.class);
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select mt from mytable mt");
        query.unwrap(SQLQuery.class).addScalar("mb", (org.hibernate.type.Type) stringType);
        List<Mailbank>results =  query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
```

but i had this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [com.usertype.StringArrayUserType] is incompatible with query return type [class [Ljava.lang.String;]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:387) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:131) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
```

please help me to read all data from db and fills array in to my array field?
thanks

Comment: No Any Body Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your first example is that you try to create your query for `values` in Java which is a `String[]`, but your JPQL asks for `MyTable` values. Which classes are not extending each other, thus you get an exception about the type incompatibility.

Something like

```
select mt.values from mytable mt
```

should give you what you want. (If it doesn't work at once, [here is some documentation about selecting values instead of entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-typedquery-expression).)